# Difference between abstract type in traits and type parameter

Tags: scala, traits, abstract-type

What is the difference in

```
trait MyTrait[T] {

  def doSomething() : T

}
```

and

```
trait MyTrait {

  type T

  def doSomething() : T

}
```

when you're implementing or mixing them in, it's looks almost the same. What are use-cases for using abstract type then?

Comment: Another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3170821/abstract-types-versus-type-parameters

Comment: I'm not sure whether to read those answers or just purchase the boxed set.