# Witness that an abstract type implements a typeclass

Tags: scala, generics, typeclass, implicit

I believe my understanding on this is correct but I'd like to check. When creating typeclasses, it feels neater to have them take a single type parameter, like `TypeClass[A]`. If the typeclass needs to be parameterized in other ways, abstract types can be used, and there is a comparison of the two approaches here:
[Abstract types versus type parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3170821/abstract-types-versus-type-parameters)

So far as I have been able to figure out, one thing which is not mentioned in the link is that if using a type parameter, you can witness that the parameter implements a (different) typeclass, likeso:

```
trait IsValidForTC[A]
    
abstract class TCWithTypeParam[A, B] (implicit ev: IsValidForTC[B]) {}
```

If I use an abstract type, I cannot be sure that it implements `IsValidForTC`:

```
abstract class TCWithAbstractType[A] (implicit ev: IsValidForTC[B]) {
    type B
} //not found: Type B
```

If so then this makes sense, but this difference isn't mentioned in the link above so I'd like to check.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's your choice whether to put implicit constraints on class level or method level. This makes impact on when the implicits are resolved.

In a type-parameter type class with implicit parameter you don't constrain the type of type class (applied to type parameters), i.e. type `TCWithTypeParam[A, B]` can be used even if there is no implicit `IsValidForTC[B]` in a scope. What you do constrain is the constructor of type class. You can emulate this behavior for type-member type class in the following way. Make the constructor private and define `apply` method (or `instance` as it's called sometimes) in companion object with desired implicit constraint

```
abstract class TCWithAbstractType[A] private {
  type B
}

object TCWithAbstractType {
  def apply[A, _B: IsValidForTC]: TCWithAbstractType[A] { type B = _B } = 
    new TCWithAbstractType[A] { type B = _B }
}
```

Comment: thanks, yes, that's a clever solution that seems to get the best of both worlds.

Comment: it seems like one potential disadvantage of this method is that when using `TCWithAbstractType`, the compiler can't "know" that `B` is guaranteed to implement `IsValidForTC`. This seems logical because `TCWithAbstractType` might have other constructors, which do not necessarily enforce the constraint that `B` implements `IsValidForTC`. This means that the typeclass witness has to be put at the method level, which is functionally OK but requires a bit more boilerplate. Have I understood the situation correctly? Let me know if I'm not being clear and I will open a new question.

Comment: @Chrisper *"when using `TCWithAbstractType`, the compiler can't "know" that `B` is guaranteed to implement `IsValidForTC`"* Depends on using how. Using **type** `TCWithTypeParam[A, B]`/`TCWithAbstractType[A] { type B =... }` isn't constrained, **instantiating** of them is constrained. *"`TCWithAbstractType` might have other constructors"* When you create `apply` method in companion object you also make **all** constructors private.

Comment: @Chrisper *"has to be put at the method level, which is functionally OK but requires a bit more boilerplate"* Difference between implicits on class level vs. method level is not in less or more boilerplate, semantics of implicit resolution is different in these cases (resolution upon constructor/`apply` method call vs. upon a method call).

Comment: thanks - I think I understand you but I'll put together a quick example and put it in a new question just to be sure.

Comment: @Chrisper Private constructors are still accessible in companion object (and implicit instances of a type class are normally defined in companion object). You can make primary constructor used in `apply` method just `private` and all secondary constructors `private[this]` (then they will not be accessible even in companion object).

Comment: @Chrisper Multiple constructors of a type class sounds odd.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the witness, but it needs to be inside the class scope so it has access to `B`:

```
abstract class TCWithAbstractType[A] {
    type B
    implicit val ev: IsValidForTC[B]
}
```

But in practice this is often less convenient than the type parameter, because it has to be implemented explicitly, something like

```
new TCWithAbstractType[A] {
    type B = ...
    implicit val ev: IsValidForTC[B] = ...
}
```

while a constructor parameter just gets the implicit value from outer scope.

Note: this is a partial duplicate of my answer to [your follow-up question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64438704/implementing-a-typeclass-using-type-parameters-versus-abstract-types), but left here in case someone stumbles on this question first.