# What's the difference between implicitly and summon?

Tags: scala, implicit, scala-3

In Scala 3 `summon` seems to do the same thing as the old `implicitly`. But when we dig into actual examples we see that isn't the case. For example

```
case class A(i: Int, s: String)

val mirror    = implicitly[Mirror.Of[A]]    
type ValueOfs = Tuple.Map[mirror.MirroredElemLabels, ValueOf]
val valueOfs  = summonAll[ValueOfs]

def values(t: Tuple): Tuple = t match
  case (h: ValueOf[_]) *: t1 => h.value *: values(t1)
  case EmptyTuple => EmptyTuple
```

produces the error

```
cannot reduce inline match with  
 scrutinee:  compiletime.erasedValue[App.ValueOfs] : App.ValueOfs  
 patterns :  case _:EmptyTuple  
             case _:*:[t @ _, ts @ _]
```

However replacing `implicitly[Mirror.Of[A]]` with `summon[Mirror.Of[A]]` compiles fine.

What are the subtleties of `summon` vs `implicitly` in this case and in general?

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67143077/2288659) may be related. Though I don't know enough about Scala 3's `Mirror` type to be able to coherently relate that to your code snippet, so I'll let someone else do the honors.

Comment: `summon` is similar to `shapeless.the` https://typelevel.org/blog/2014/01/18/implicitly_existential.html https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65634897/in-scala-2-13-why-is-it-sometimes-impossible-to-summon-type-class-explicitly https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65062041/behaviour-of-context-bounds-and-implicit-parameter-lists-with-regards-to-path-de https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64438704/implementing-a-typeclass-using-type-parameters-versus-abstract-types

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given

```
case class A(i: Int, s: String)
```

we can see that `summon` and `implicitly` return the same runtime value

```
assert(implicitly[Mirror.Of[A]] eq summon[Mirror.Of[A]])
```

but they have different compile time types

```
def fun[A,B]( a: A, b: B )( implicit ev: A =:= B ) = ???
fun(implicitly[Mirror.Of[A]], summon[Mirror.Of[A]])
    Cannot prove that deriving.Mirror.Of[Worksheet.A] =:= (
      deriving.Mirror{
        MirroredType = Worksheet.A; MirroredMonoType = Worksheet.A; 
          MirroredElemTypes <: Tuple
      }
     & 
      scala.deriving.Mirror.Product{
        MirroredMonoType = Worksheet.A; MirroredType = Worksheet.A; 
          MirroredLabel = ("A" : String)
      }
    ){
      MirroredElemTypes = (Int, String); 
        MirroredElemLabels = (("i" : String), ("s" : String))
    }.
```

The one returned by `summon` is more specific, although I'm not sure how/why this applies to the case in the question.