# Message equivalent of dependent method types

Tags: scala, akka, type-systems

Thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7860163/what-are-some-compelling-use-cases-for-dependent-method-types) post I'm getting my head around dependent method types.  I have a  structure similar to the following

```
trait Environment{
    type Population <: PopulationBase
    protected trait PopulationBase

    def evolveUs(population: Population): Population
}

object FactoredOut{
    def evolvePopulation(env: Environment)(prevPopulation: env.Population): env.Population = {
        env.evolveUs(prevPopulation)
    }
}
```

I now want to start using actors to spread the work in the `FactoredOut` part across a cluster. To do this I need a way to pass immutable messages which carry the `Environment`.

Obviously *the following doesn't work*, but demonstrates what I'm trying to do

```
object Messages{
    case class EvolvePopulation(env: Environment)(prevPopulation: env.Population)
}
```

What is the correct way to pass the population and it's enclosing environment around?

(Would have added the dependent-method-types tag, but I don't have enough points to add a 'new' tag)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your intuition that you need to pack up both the value of the dependent type (`env.Population`) and the value that the type depends on (`env`) as a single object is exactly right.

Given the definitions you've already posted, probably the simplest approach would be something like this,

```
// Type representing the packaging up of an environment and a population
// from that environment
abstract class EvolvePopulation {
  type E <: Environment
  val env : E
  val prevPopulation : env.Population
}

object EvolvePopulation {
  def apply(env0 : Environment)(prevPopulation0 : env0.Population) =
    new EvolvePopulation {
      type E = env0.type
      val env : E = env0 // type annotation required to prevent widening from
                         // the singleton type
      val prevPopulation = prevPopulation0
    }
}
```

Now if we define a concrete environment type,

```
class ConcreteEnvironment extends Environment {
  class Population extends PopulationBase
  def evolveUs(population: Population): Population = population
}
```

we can use it directly as before,

```
val e1 = new ConcreteEnvironment

val p1 = new e1.Population
val p2 = e1.evolveUs(p1)
val p3 = e1.evolveUs(p2)
```

and we can also package up an environment and population for distribution,

```
def distrib(ep : EvolvePopulation) {
  import ep._
  val p4 = env.evolveUs(prevPopulation)
  val p5 = env.evolveUs(p4)
  val p6 = env.evolveUs(p5)
}

val ep1 = EvolvePopulation(e1)(p3)

distrib(ep1)
```

Comment: Fantastic, as ever.  Wouldn't have been following this at all if it hadn't been for the type system deep dive on your course.