# Abstract type vs. type parameter - where is the difference?

Tags: scala, type-parameter, abstract-type

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Scala: Abstract Types vs Generics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1154571/scala-abstract-types-vs-generics)

Chapter 20.6 'Abstract types' of 'Programming in Scala' explains the use of an abstract type with an example that ends in the following resulting code:

```
class Food
abstract class Animal {
  type SuitableFood <: Food
  def eat(food: SuitableFood)
}

class Grass extends Food
class Cow extends Animal {
  type SuitableFood = Grass
  override def eat(food: Grass) {}
}
```

With these definitions, an object of `Cow` can not eat a fish:

```
class Fish extends Food
val bessy: Animal = new Cow
bessy eat (new Fish) // Error, type mismatch
```

After reading this good example about the use of an abstract type, I was wondering, why we do not just use a type parameter instead ?

```
class Food
abstract class Animal[T <: Food] { 
  def eat(food: T)
}

class Grass extends Food
class Cow extends Animal[Grass] {
  override def eat(food: Grass){}
}

class Fish extends Food
val bessy: Animal[Grass] = new Cow
bessy eat (new Fish) // Also ends in a type mismatch error !
```

Where is the difference using type parameter instead of an abstract type here ?

Answer (score 2):

Martin Odersky answered that question in [this](http://www.artima.com/scalazine/articles/scalas_type_system.html#abstracttypes) interview.

> There have always been two notions of abstraction: parameterization and abstract members. In Java you also have both, but
>   it depends on what you are abstracting over. In Java you have abstract
>   methods, but you can't pass a method as a parameter. You don't have
>   abstract fields, but you can pass a value as a parameter. And
>   similarly you don't have abstract type members, but you can specify a
>   type as a parameter. So in Java you also have all three of these, but
>   there's a distinction about what abstraction principle you can use for
>   what kinds of things. And you could argue that this distinction is
>   fairly arbitrary.
>
> What we did in Scala was try to be more complete and orthogonal. We decided to have the same construction principles for all three
>   sorts of members. So you can have abstract fields as well as value
>   parameters. You can pass methods (or "functions") as parameters, or
>   you can abstract over them. You can specify types as parameters, or
>   you can abstract over them. And what we get conceptually is that we
>   can model one in terms of the other. At least in principle, we can
>   express every sort of parameterization as a form of object-oriented
>   abstraction. So in a sense you could say Scala is a more orthogonal
>   and complete language.

That said, there are some subtle differences between the two, but I can't recall them off the top of my head.

You might also want to have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7860163/what-are-some-compelling-use-cases-for-dependent-method-types) thread.