# Type upper bound in Scala Mapper/Record traits

Tags: scala, lift

I am puzzled by what seems to be a standard pattern in the Lift's Mapper and Record frameworks:

```
trait Mapper[A<:Mapper[A]] extends BaseMapper {
  self: A =>
  type MapperType = A
```

What does it mean with regard to the type parameter of the Mapper trait? The type A, which is a parameter of Mapper, is required to be a subclass of Mapper[A], how is it even possible, or may be I just don't understand the meaning of this definition.

Comment: For the record, the kind of recursion you see in the type parameter is called [_F_-bounded polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_quantification). Most languages with generics support it, including Scala and Java.

Answer (score 2):

This pattern is used to be able to capture the actual subtype of `Mapper`, which is useful for accepting arguments of that exact type in methods.

Traditionally you can't declare that constraint:

```
scala> trait A { def f(other: A): A  }
defined trait A

scala> class B extends A { def f(other: B): B = sys.error("TODO") }
<console>:11: error: class B needs to be abstract, 
since method f in trait A of type (other: A)A is not defined
(Note that A does not match B)
   class B extends A { def f(other: B): B = sys.error("TODO") }
```

While when you have access to the precise type you can do:

```
scala> trait A[T <: A[T]] { def f(other: T): T  }
defined trait A

scala> class B extends A[B] { def f(other: B): B = sys.error("TODO") }
defined class B
```

Note that this is also possible via bounded type members:

```
 trait A { type T <: A; def f(other: T): T }
 class B extends A { type T <: B; def f(other: T): T = sys.error("TODO") }
```

Comment: You might also find Miles Sabin's answer on dependent method types interesting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7860163/what-are-some-compelling-use-cases-for-dependent-method-types