# Values of abstract member types

Tags: scala, type-members

I'm trying to use this kind of code:

```
trait Outer {
  type Inner

  def f(x:Inner) : Void 
}

object test {
  def apply(o: Outer, i : Outer#Inner) : Void = 
    o.f(i)
}
```

I got an error in the last but one line:

> type mismatch;  found   : i.type (with underlying type Outer#Inner)  required: o.Inner

If I change apply's signature to

```
def apply(o: Outer, i : o.Inner) : Void
```

then I got an error:

> illegal dependent method type

Is it possible to get this piece of code work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can take advantage of method dependent types (see [What are some compelling use cases for dependent method types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7860163/what-are-some-compelling-use-cases-for-dependent-method-types) by example).
This will require you to use 2 parameter lists:

```
trait Outer {
  type Inner
  def f(x:Inner): Unit 
}

object test {
  def apply( o: Outer )( i : o.Inner) { o.f(i) }
}
```

Comment: Well, that works, many thanks! But imo o.Inner is much uglyier than Outer#Inner. Would you explain, what the point of use former instead of latter? The compiler can do only static checks so o.Inner should be equal o.type#Inner which should be (statically) equal to Outer#Inner. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

> But imo `o.Inner` is much uglyier than `Outer#Inner`. Would you explain, what the point of use former instead of latter? The compiler can do only static checks so `o.Inner` should be equal `o.type#Inner` which should be (statically) equal to `Outer#Inner`. Am I missing something?

Here is the reason. Imagine you had

```
class Outer1 extends Outer {
  type Inner = Int

  def apply(i: Int) { ... }
}

class Outer2 extends Outer {
  type Inner = String

  def apply(i: Int) { ... }
}
```

Should `test.apply(new Outer1, "abc")` compile? Obviously not, since it'll call `Outer1.apply(String)`, which doesn't exist. But then, `test.apply(new Outer1, 1)` can't compile either (otherwise you are back to path-dependent types) and there is no way to use this `apply` at all!