# DI in Scala with Cake Pattern

Tags: scala, dependency-injection

This [article](http://jonasboner.com/real-world-scala-dependency-injection-di/) explains Dependency Injection via Scala's `Cake Pattern`.

My understanding of this pattern's benefit is that traits can be mixed in (production v. test) with static checking.

In Mr. Bonér's example, he lists this finished (per example) code:

**UserRepositoryComponent** and **UserServiceComponent**

I added comments per my understanding.

```
trait UserRepositoryComponent {
  val userRepository: UserRepository    // stand-alone component

  class UserRepository {      
    ...                      // actual implementation here
  }
} 
trait UserServiceComponent { 
  this: UserRepositoryComponent =>      //Requires a mixed-in UserRepo*Component

  val userService: UserService  

  class UserService {
    ...                      // actual implementation here
  }
}
```

My understanding is that the `Service` depends on injection of a `Repository` component.

For production purposes, the following can be used to wire a "production" `Repository` component into the `UserServiceComponent`:

```
object ComponentRegistry extends 
  UserServiceComponent with 
  UserRepositoryComponent 
{
  val userRepository = new UserRepository
  val userService = new UserService
}
```

If our production code wanted to use the `userRepository` or `userService`, is the correct way to use them via a simple `import`?

I *think* that I understand half of the article up to this point, but I'm not sure how to use the `ComponentRegistry` object.

Comment: Recommend http://parleys.com/play/53a7d2cce4b0543940d9e55b/about

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're running head first into the bakery of doom bro:
[What are some compelling use cases for dependent method types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7860163/what-are-some-compelling-use-cases-for-dependent-method-types/7861070#7861070)

To answer your question, the proper way to use `userService` would be to use another trait and cake it up:

```
trait Example { this: UserServiceComponent => 
   def getExampleUser() = userService.getUser("ExampleUser")
}
```

Now whatever this new trait does isn't directly coupled to anything like the object `ComponentRegistry`. Instead your application becomes this:

```
object Application extends 
  Example with
  UserServiceComponent with 
  UserRepositoryComponent 
{
  val userRepository = new UserRepository
  val userService = new UserService
}
```

Anyway, you should run for the hills because if you really want to use cake you should be doing something more like this:

```
trait UserRepositoryComponent {

  type UserRepository <: UserRepositoryLike

  val userRepository: UserRepository

  trait UserRepositoryLike {
    def getUserOrSomething()
  }

}

trait UserRepositoryComponentImpl extends UserRepositoryComponent {

  type UserRepository = UserRepositoryImpl
  val userRepository = new UserRepositoryImpl

  class UserRepositoryImpl extends UserRepositoryLike {
    override def getUserOrSomething() = ???
  }

}

trait UserServiceComponent {
  this: UserRepositoryComponent =>

  type UserService <: UserServiceLike
  val userService: UserService

  trait UserServiceLike {
    def getUserNameById(id: Int): String
  }

}

trait UserServiceComponentImpl extends UserServiceComponent {
  this: UserRepositoryComponent =>

  type UserService = UserServiceImpl
  val userService = new UserServiceImpl

  class UserServiceImpl extends UserServiceLike {
    override def getUserNameById(id: Int) = userRepository.getUserOrSomething
  }

}

trait Example {
  this: UserServiceComponent =>

  def getExampleUser() = userService.getUserNameById(1)

}

object Application extends
Example with
UserRepositoryComponentImpl with
UserServiceComponentImpl
```

Now save yourself some time, drop the cake pattern, and do something [simple](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZasXwtTRkio).

Comment: One day, people will stop engineering bs patterns for DI and go back to passing arguments. I want to believe...

Comment: Am I returning to the bakery of doom [here](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/98066/cake-pattern-code)?