# What does HList#foldLeft() return?

Tags: scala, shapeless

I'm trying to play with HList's from Shapeless.

This is my first try:

```
trait Column[T] {
     val name: String
}

case class CV[T](col: Column[T], value: T)

object CV {
    object columnCombinator extends Poly2 {
        implicit def algo[A] = at[(String, String, String), CV[A]] { case ((suffix, separator, sql), cv) ⇒
            (suffix, separator, if (sql == "") cv.col.name+suffix else sql+separator+cv.col.name+suffix)
        }
    }

    def combine[A <: HList](columns: A, suffix: String, separator: String = " and ")
                           (implicit l: LeftFolder[A, (String, String, String), columnCombinator.type]): String =
        columns.foldLeft((suffix, separator, ""))(columnCombinator)._3
}
```

The problem is I don't know what `foldLeft` does return in this example.

I expect it to return `(String, String, String)`, but the compiler tells me that returns `l.Out`.  What is `l.Out`?

The source code is a little complicated to guess it.

There isn't much information in the web about this.

Some information I've consulted:

- [Shapeless Tests](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/master/core/src/test/scala/shapeless/hlist.scala)
- [Shapeless documentation](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/wiki/Feature-overview:-shapeless-2.0.0)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your `combine` method returns what's called a ["dependent method type"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7861070/334519), which just means that its return type depends on one of its arguments—in this case as a path-dependent type that includes `l` in its path.

In many cases the compiler will statically know something about the dependent return type, but in your example it doesn't. I'll try to explain why in a second, but first consider the following simpler example:

```
scala> trait Foo { type A; def a: A }
defined trait Foo

scala> def fooA(foo: Foo): foo.A = foo.a
fooA: (foo: Foo)foo.A

scala> fooA(new Foo { type A = String; def a = "I'm a StringFoo" })
res0: String = I'm a StringFoo
```

Here the inferred type of `res0` is `String`, since the compiler statically knows that the `A` of the `foo` argument is `String`. We can't write either of the following, though:

```
scala> def fooA(foo: Foo): String = foo.a
<console>:12: error: type mismatch;
 found   : foo.A
 required: String
       def fooA(foo: Foo): String = foo.a
                                        ^

scala> def fooA(foo: Foo) = foo.a.substring
<console>:12: error: value substring is not a member of foo.A
       def fooA(foo: Foo) = foo.a.substring
                                  ^
```

Because here the compiler doesn't statically know that `foo.A` is `String`.

Here's a more complex example:

```
sealed trait Baz {
  type A
  type B

  def b: B
}

object Baz {
  def makeBaz[T](t: T): Baz { type A = T; type B = T } = new Baz {
    type A = T
    type B = T

    def b = t
  }
}
```

Now *we* know that it's not possible to create a `Baz` with different types for `A` and `B`, but the compiler doesn't, so it won't accept the following:

```
scala> def bazB(baz: Baz { type A = String }): String = baz.b
<console>:13: error: type mismatch;
 found   : baz.B
 required: String
       def bazB(baz: Baz { type A = String }): String = baz.b
                                                            ^
```

This is exactly what you're seeing. If we look at the code in `shapeless.ops.hlist`, we can convince ourselves that the `LeftFolder` we're creating here will have the same type for `In` and `Out`, but the compiler can't (or rather *won't*—it's a design decision) follow us in this reasoning, which means it won't let us treat `l.Out` as a tuple without more evidence.

Fortunately that evidence is pretty easy to provide thanks to `LeftFolder.Aux`, which is just an alias for `LeftFolder` with the `Out` type member as a fourth type parameter:

```
def combine[A <: HList](columns: A, suffix: String, separator: String = " and ")(
  implicit l: LeftFolder.Aux[
    A,
    (String, String, String),
    columnCombinator.type,
    (String, String, String)
  ]
): String =
    columns.foldLeft((suffix, separator, ""))(columnCombinator)._3
```

(You could also use the type member syntax with plain old `LeftFolder` in `l`'s type, but that would make this signature even messier.)

The `columns.foldLeft(...)(...)` part still returns `l.Out`, but now the compiler statically knows that that's a tuple of strings.

Comment: You've explained a complex concept in an easy to understand way.  Congrats!!

Comment: Very nice answer Travis :) I wish the docs were more like this

Comment: What about if `foldLeft()` returns a tuple that contains a HList?.  It compiles, but when I try to use it, the compiler complains about implicits.  If necessary, I can create another question.

Comment: You can add implicit arguments that provide evidence about the type. Probably worth another question, though.

Answer (score 0):

After having read the complete answer from Travis, here is a little variation of his solution:

```
type CombineTuple = (String, String, String)

def combine[A <: HList](columns: A, suffix: String, separator: String = " and ")(
  implicit l: LeftFolder[
    A,
    CombineTuple,
    columnCombinator.type
  ]
): String =
    columns.foldLeft((suffix, separator, ""))(columnCombinator).asInstanceof[CombineTuple]._3
```

In this way, the implicit signature is shorter, as it is needed in many methods that call this one.

*UPDATED*: As Travis has explained in comments, it is bestter to use `LeftFolder.Aux`.

Comment: This won't compile, though, since `LeftFolder.Aux` needs four type parameters. The cast with `asInstanceOf` also makes the code fragile—you're giving up type safety when you cast, so e.g. the compiler may not be able to tell you if you make a change that breaks something.

Comment: Corrected: LeftFolder.Aux --> LeftFolder.

Comment: When using `LeftFolder.Aux`, and I specify a wrong return type, does the compiler detect it?.

Comment: No, `asInstanceOf` is a straight-up cast, so you can put in any type you like and you won't know if it works until runtime.