# How to transform an HList to another HList with foldRight/foldLeft

Tags: scala, shapeless

This question is derived from my previous question: [What does HList#foldLeft() return?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26608766/what-does-hlistfoldleft-return/26625539#26625539)

I have this scenario:

```
class Cursor {
}

trait Column[T] {
   def read(c: Cursor, index: Int): T
}

object Columns {
    object readColumn extends Poly2 {
        implicit def a[A, B <: HList] = at[Column[A], (B, Cursor, Int)] { case (col, (values, cursor, index)) ⇒
            (col.read(cursor, index) :: values, cursor, index+1)
        }
    }

    def readColumns[A <: HList, B <: HList](c: Cursor, columns: A)(implicit l: RightFolder.Aux[A, (HNil.type, Cursor, Int), readColumn.type, (B, Cursor, Int)]): B =
        columnas.foldRight((HNil, c, 0))(readColumn)._1
}
```

This code, tries to read the values of several columns.

If I call `readColumns(cursor, new Column[String] :: new Column[Int] :: HNil)`, I expect to get `String :: Int :: HNil`.

The `readColumns()` method compiles ok, but the compiler complains about implicits in concrete invocations.

What is the right way of working?.

**UPDATE 1**:

Here is the exact error message I'm receiving when invoking with 2 columns:

```
could not find implicit value for parameter l: 
shapeless.ops.hlist.RightFolder.Aux[shapeless.::[Column[String],shapeless.::
[Column[String],shapeless.HNil]],(shapeless.HNil.type, android.database.Cursor, Int),readColumn.type,(B, android.database.Cursor, Int)]
```

Don't know how to help the compiler.  :-(

**UPDATE 2**:

Question: why specify `HNil.type` in the implicit parameter of `readColumns()`: `RightFolder.Aux[A, (HNil.type, Cursor, Int), readColumn.type, (B, Cursor, Int)]` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Update to address edits

Here's a complete working example:

```
class Cursor {}

trait Column[T] {
   def read(c: Cursor, index: Int): T
}

import shapeless._, ops.hlist.RightFolder

object Columns {
  object readColumn extends Poly2 {
    implicit def a[A, B <: HList]: Case.Aux[
      Column[A],
      (B, Cursor, Int),
      (A :: B, Cursor, Int)
    ] = at[Column[A], (B, Cursor, Int)] {
      case (col, (values, cursor, index)) =>
        (col.read(cursor, index) :: values, cursor, index + 1)
    }
  }

  def readColumns[A <: HList, B <: HList](c: Cursor, columns: A)(implicit
    l: RightFolder.Aux[
      A,
      (HNil, Cursor, Int),
      readColumn.type,
      (B, Cursor, Int)
    ]
  ): B = columns.foldRight((HNil: HNil, c, 0))(readColumn)._1
}
```

And then:

```
val stringColumn = new Column[String] {
  def read(c: Cursor, index: Int) = "foo"
}

val intColumn = new Column[Int] {
  def read(c: Cursor, index: Int) = 10
}

Columns.readColumns(new Cursor, stringColumn :: intColumn :: HNil)
```

This compiles just fine and does what I'd expect on both 2.0.0 and 2.1.0-RC1.

And I should have mentioned in my original answer that using `HNil.type` like that isn't ideal—it works just fine, but explicitly typing the `HNil` in the argument to `foldRight` as `HNil` is a better solution. Note that you have to do one or the other, since the static type of `HNil` is `HNil.type`, and `RightFolder` isn't covariant in its second argument.

## Original answer

There's a very minor error in your `readColumn` definition—you're returning a `Tuple4`, but you want to return a `Tuple3`. The following should work:

```
    object readColumn extends Poly2 {
       implicit def a[A, B <: HList]: Case.Aux[
         Column[A],
         (B, Cursor, Int),
         (A :: B, Cursor, Int)
       ] = at[Column[A], (B, Cursor, Int)] {
          case (col, (values, cursor, index)) =>
           (col.read(cursor, index) :: values, cursor, index+1)
       }
    }
```

It's usually a good idea to provide an explicit return type for any implicit method for unrelated reasons having to do with implicit resolution, but in this case being explicit about the return type also turns up the error pretty quickly.

Comment: Thanks, it is now better. Why do I have to specify `HNil.type` for `readColumns()` implicit parameter?.  It still doesn't work for concrete invocations. :-(

Comment: Hmm, invoking `readColumns` worked for me when I set up a simple example. I'll take a look, but probably won't have a chance until later this afternoon.

Comment: I've updated the question with the exact error message I'm receiving, for better diagnostic.

Comment: Note that in the expression `HNil: HNil`,  the first term refers to `object HNil` whereas the 2nd to `trait HNil`.

Comment: Your sample works ok in the Scala REPL, but not in regular source files.  I keep having the problem with compiler not being able to generate the implicit parameter to `readColumns()`.  Shapeless is powerful but tricky. :-(