# Having trouble with defining subclass function

Tags: scala

I have the following abstract classes:

```
abstract class Accessor {

  def get(rowkey:String): Option[M2mModel]
  def insertNew(model: M2mModel): Option[M2mModel]


}

abstract class Model(active:Int) {

  @BeanProperty
  var ttl = None

}
```

My implementation classes are:

```
object AccountModel {
  val COL_USERNAME = "username"
  val COL_EMAIL = "email"
  val COL_PASSWORD = "password"
  val COL_DOMAIN = "domain"
  val COL_ACTIVE = "active"
  val COL_ROLE = "role"
  val COL_ACLID = "aclid"

  val definedFields = List(COL_USERNAME, COL_EMAIL, COL_PASSWORD, COL_DOMAIN, 
    COL_ACTIVE, COL_ROLE, COL_ACLID)

  def apply(rowkey:String, email:String, password:String) = new AccountModel(rowkey, email, password) 

}


case class AccountModel(rowkey: String, email:String, password: Option[String], 
  username: Option[String], domain: Option[String],
  role: Option[String], active: Int, aclid: Option[String]) extends M2mModel(active) {

  def this(rowkey:String, email:String, password:String) = this(rowkey, email, Some(password),
      None, None, None, 1, None)

}
```

When I create the Accessor class and implement the insertNew method I get the following error:
object creation impossible, since method insertNew in class Accessor of type (model: 
 package.Model)Option[package.Model] is not defined (Note that 
 package.Model does not match package.AccountModel)

Here is my implementing class

```
object AccountAccess extends Accessor {
 def insertNew(model: AccountModel): Option[AccountModel] = {

    ...do stuff
}
```

what am i doing wrong?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that the `insertNew` method requires something of type M2mModel and it can be implemented only by a method that resolves to the same signature.

In Scala, we can solve this in two ways.

#### Type Parametrization

We can consider the Accessor as a generic class which works with something of type T that extends M2mModel:

```
abstract class Accessor[T <: M2mModel] {
    def get(rowkey:String): Option[T]
    def insertNew(model: T): Option[T]
}
```

And extend `AccountAccess` from this like so:

```
object AccountAccess extends Accessor[AccountModel] {
    def insertNew(model: AccountModel): Option[AccountModel] = {
        ???
    }

    def get(rowkey: String) = ???
}
```

#### Abstract type members

We can consider `Accessor` to be a class which in its implementation handles objects of some abstract type `T` that extends `M2mModel`:

```
abstract class Accessor {

    type T <: M2mModel

    def get(rowkey:String): Option[T]
    def insertNew(model: T): Option[T]

}
```

Extending classes, in this case `AccountAccess`, should specify what this type `T` is supposed to be:

```
object AccountAccess extends Accessor {

    type T = AccountModel

    def get(rowkey: String) = ???

    def insertNew(model: AccountModel) = ???
}
```

Personally, I do belive that the second choice is the better approach.

You can find a very interesting discussion about this here:

[Scala: Abstract types vs generics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1154571/scala-abstract-types-vs-generics)

Do read it since it will help you solve this kind of problems in a very elegant and modular way in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're narrowing the scope of insertNew in your object, so it no longer meets it's requirements. Your insertNew method can only take classes greater than `M2mModel` not lower.

This should work:

```
 def insertNew(model: M2mModel): Option[M2mModel]
```

And this:

```
 def insertNew(model: Any): Option[Any]
```

Imagine if you passed this object to something that only knew about M2mModel and not AccountModel. The function insertNew only takes AccountModel so another M2mModel wouldn't work.