# What does Scala's "type" keyword mean?

Tags: scala, types, interface, traits

Scala type system drives me mad. I'm starting looking in the source code of basic scala packages and it spins my brain off.

Can some one please elaborate why we do need to define type if Sequence is already a trait(aka interface)? I'm coming from Java work where type is class or an interface but in scala type seems more that that.

```
package object scala {
  ....

   type Seq[+A] = scala.collection.Sequence[A] 
   val Seq = scala.collection.Sequence

 ....
 }
```

Comment: The first definition is just an alias, it allows you to shorten the type (you wouldn't want to write every time `scala.collection.Sequence[A]`). Also this sentence: _why we do need to define type if Sequence is already a trait(aka interface)?_ doesn't make much sense, and last, traits are not interfaces.

Comment: I don't really know scala but I think this is just a type-abbreviation - just to make things shorter

Comment: @EndeNeu what about import? Import could solve this problem.

Comment: That's true, but the fact that this kind of aliases are in the package file makes them implicitly available, when you use the `Seq` type you don't have to add another import to your file, it's already there for you.

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at [Understanding what 'type' does in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19492542/understanding-what-type-keyword-does-in-scala) for why you need the keyword type in addition to classes and traits. Regarding why scala package object contains these aliases, it is present in the comment at the top of the file "Core Scala types. They are always available without an explicit import." https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.11.x/src/library/scala/package.scala