# Why can I use StringBuilder without explicitly importing it in scala?

Tags: scala, import, stringbuilder

I'm using scala 2.11.0

I notice StringBuilder is defined in scala.collection.mutable.StringBuilder and java.lang.StringBuilder. I also notice scala implicitly import java.lang.*, scala.*, scala.Predef._

Why am I using scala.collection.mutable.StringBuilder and not java.lang.StringBuilder when I write

```
val def = new StringBuilder
```

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check what scala import via looking into [package.scala](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/27da46343cd545534819300235bc64ab74958c92/src/library/scala/package.scala)

Lines 74-45 imports StringBuilder by

```
type StringBuilder = scala.collection.mutable.StringBuilder
val StringBuilder = scala.collection.mutable.StringBuilder
```

Answer (score 2):

Well because everything [here](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.11.x/src/library/scala/package.scala) is available by default. i.e. `scala._` is by default available.

In that package object you can see:

```
 type StringBuilder = scala.collection.mutable.StringBuilder
```

This is why doing `new StringBuilder` takes `scala.collection.mutable.StringBuilder` and not `java.lang.StringBuilder`

Answer (score 0):

Scala uses type aliasing to ensure that core scala types are available without an import.

https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/27da46343cd545534819300235bc64ab74958c92/src/library/scala/package.scala#L74 will take you to the type alias declaration.

This link will also help - [Understanding what 'type' keyword does in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19492542/understanding-what-type-keyword-does-in-scala)

Note that since the type alias declaration is in the Scala package object, and scala._ is imported implicitly, it bring the type alias declaration into the scope for every compilation unit.