# Scala types redux

Tags: scala, types

I **thought** I had a good understanding of the proper use of the type keyword in Scala, from reading these articles:

[Understanding what 'type' keyword does in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19492542/understanding-what-type-keyword-does-in-scala)
[Scala: Abstract types vs generics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1154571/scala-abstract-types-vs-generics)

However, I'm not clear as to why the following code will not compile. With AddableNum being defined as it is, I should be able define add() for anything that defines addition between two integers, yes?  Ah, but no!  What am I missing?

```
type Nums <:Int
type AddableNum <: { def +(x:Nums): Nums}
class MyNum (value:AddableNum) {
    def add (that:Nums) : Nums = value + that
}
val i:Int = 5
val test = new MyNum(i)  // DOES NOT COMPILE
```

Comment: '+' is defined on Int but 'that' is a AddableNum

Comment: Yes, thank you!  OK so I think I have fixed that problem with the revised code. But see the new compile problem.

Answer (score 1):

Few issues in your code, try to use code below:

```
type Nums = Int // should use '=', because AddableNum can't refer to abstract type 

// AddableNum is a type alias for structural type definition
// should use AnyVal for accept Int (by default AnyRef) 
type AddableNum = AnyVal { def +(x:Nums): Nums} 

class MyNum[T <: AddableNum](value: T) { // use type constraints here (instead line above)
  def add (that:Nums) : Nums = value + that
}

val i:Int = 5
val test = new MyNum(i)  // COMPILE
```