# Accessing type-member in Scala

Tags: scala, types

I have a toy class with type member `T`.

```
class A { type T = Int }
```

How can I access my type member. e.g. get the type or modify it.

```
val a = new A
a.T = String //error: value T is not a member of A
```

Since `T` is my member , why I can not access it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Type members are more like generic parameters than regular class members.  Like a generic parameter, you cannot reassign a type parameter or access it from an instance of the class.  Read more about type members [here](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/abstract-types.html), and the difference between abstract types and generic parameters [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1154571/scala-abstract-types-vs-generics).

Comment: In the OP's case it isn't abstract, it's fixed to `Int`. It's just that type members cannot be accessed or reassigned like values.

Answer (score 3):

You can't access it as a value, but you can access it as a type:

```
scala> class A { type T = Int }
scala> val a = new A
scala> val someInt: a.T = 5
someInt: a.T = 5
```