# Scala Mutually Convertible Generic Types

Tags: scala, generics, types

I'm very new to Scala programming, and I really like the degree to which code is composable. I wanted to write some traits that deal with two related objects that are convertible to each other, and build more functionality by continuing to extend that trait so that when I create objects I can specify the related types for my generics. Here is a working toy example of the type of code I'm talking about:

```
trait FirstConverter[First] {
  def toFirst: First
}

trait SecondConverter[Second] {
  def toSecond: Second
}

trait TwoWayConverter[First <: SecondConverter[Second], Second <: FirstConverter[First]] {
  def firstToSecond(x: First) = x.toSecond
  def secondToFirst(x: Second) = x.toFirst
}

trait RoundTripConverter[First <: SecondConverter[Second], Second <: FirstConverter[First]] extends TwoWayConverter[First, Second] {
  def firstToFirst(x: First) = secondToFirst(firstToSecond(x))
  def secondToSecond(x: Second) = firstToSecond(secondToFirst(x))
}

case class A(s: String) extends SecondConverter[B] {
  def toSecond: B = B((s.toInt) + 1)
}

case class B(i: Int) extends FirstConverter[A] {
  def toFirst: A = A((i * 2).toString)
}

object ABConverter extends RoundTripConverter[A, B]

object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println(ABConverter firstToSecond A("10")) // 11
    println(ABConverter secondToFirst B(42)) // 84
    println(ABConverter firstToFirst A("1")) // 4
    println(ABConverter secondToSecond B(2)) // 5
  }
}
```

While this works, I'm not sure if it's idiomatic Scala. I'm asking if there are any tricks to make the type definitions more concise and if I can somehow define the type restrictions only once and have them used by multiple traits which extend other traits.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: A stylistic pet peeve only perhaps: I do not like postfix operations for `toInt` or `toString` in this code - I do not think they add anything here, to me they only harm readability a bit. In particular I prefer `foo.s.toInt + 1` over `(s toInt) + 1`.

Comment: @Suma - true, I'm still learning when to use the period and when not. Added those back in.

Comment: @Wolfgang - I've searched in the same direction one time.  See, what I got: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1154571/scala-abstract-types-vs-generics/10891994#10891994

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to improve your design would be to use a type class instead of inheriting from `FirstConverter` and `SecondConverter`. That way you could use multiple conversion functions for the same types and convert between classes you don't control yourself.

One way would be to create a type class which can convert an `A` into a `B` :

```
trait Converter[A, B] {
  def convert(a: A): B
}

trait TwoWayConverter[A, B] {
  def firstToSecond(a: A)(implicit conv: Converter[A, B]): B = conv.convert(a)
  def secondToFirst(b: B)(implicit conv: Converter[B, A]): A = conv.convert(b)
}

trait RoundTripConverter[A, B] extends TwoWayConverter[A, B] {
  def firstToFirst(a: A)(implicit convAB: Converter[A, B], convBA: Converter[B, A]) =
    secondToFirst(firstToSecond(a))
  def secondToSecond(b: B)(implicit convAB: Converter[A, B], convBA: Converter[B, A]) =
    firstToSecond(secondToFirst(b))
}
```

We could create type class instances for the following two classes `Foo` and `Bar` similar to your `A` and `B`

```
case class Foo(s: String)
case class Bar(i: Int)

implicit val convFooBarFoor = new Converter[Foo, Bar] {
  def convert(foo: Foo) = Bar((foo.s toInt) + 1)
}

implicit val convBarFoo = new Converter[Bar, Foo] {
  def convert(bar: Bar) = Foo((bar.i * 2) toString)
}
```

We then could create a `FooBarConverter` :

```
object FooBarConverter extends RoundTripConverter[Foo, Bar]

FooBarConverter firstToSecond Foo("10")  // Bar(11)
FooBarConverter secondToFirst Bar(42)    // Foo(84)
FooBarConverter firstToFirst Foo("1")    // Foo(4)
FooBarConverter secondToSecond Bar(2)    // Bar(5)
```

The only problem is because we can not pass parameters to a trait, we can not limit the types to types with a `Converter` type class instance. So you can create the `StringIntConverter` below even if no `Converter[String, Int]` and/or `Convert[Int, String]` instances exist.

```
object StringIntConverter extends TwoWayConverter[String, Int]
```

You cannot call `StringIntConverter.firstToSecond("a")` because the `firstToSecond` method needs the implicit evidence of the two mentioned type class instances.

Comment: "You cannot call `StringIntConverter.firstToSecond("a")`" - fortunately this is still detected compile time, therefore it does not seem like serious limitation.

Comment: I would prefer `implicit object convBarFoo extends Converter[Bar, Foo]` over `implicit val convBarFoo = new Converter[Bar, Foo]` to avoid anonymous class, but your taste may vary.

Comment: @Peter Neyens - thanks for the new approach. I like how this keeps the types "clean" and how my functionality could be added on to types I don't control. I was wondering where is the best place to define the `implicit Converter`s, inside the object that `extends RoundTripConverter`? This was the only way I could get your code to compile, and unfortunately I seem to have to use `implicit` parameters to any functions that use this instead of having `implicit val`s in my traits. Any suggestions how to avoid that verbosity?