# Why do we need to specify a refined type (or its equivalent Aux) for the output of certain type computations?

Tags: scala, dependent-type, type-level-computation, path-dependent-type

In https://jto.github.io/articles/typelevel_quicksort :

We are exposed to a `Sum` type whose `apply` looks like this:

```
def apply[A <: Nat, B <: Nat](implicit sum: Sum[A, B]): Aux[A, B, sum.Out] = sum
```

Now, we could use type refinement directly instead of Aux, but the question remains: why is this (the explicit return type) necessary? Wouldn't it be "obvious" that the return type of `apply` would have a Sum#Out type equal to sum.Out?

If we remove it and we just use `val x = Sum[_0, _1]`, it looks fine, except adding `val y = Sum[x.Out, _1]` will not work, saying the compiler couldn't find the implicit Sum.

How come the compiler seems to "forget" the exact type of x.Out?

Comment: As far as I see `Sum#Out` would mean the `Out` for any `Sum` instance, whereas `sum.Out` means the `Out` for one specific `sum: Sum` instance

Comment: @cchantep I suppose part of the reason is why Scala doesn't infer the sum.Out rather than Sum#Out?

Comment: I dont sée the point...

Comment: I think we might be getting off track... let's go back to the question of why the compiler forgets x.Out?

Comment: Did you mean to ask "why is the return type of `apply` not inferred as `Sum[A,B]{type Out = sum.Out}` by default"?

Comment: I think that's a closely related question. Feel free to answer that too haha.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Types `Sum[A, B]` and `Sum.Aux[A, B, C] = Sum[A, B] { type Out = C }` are different. The latter is a subtype of the former. Also `Sum[A, B]` is existential type `Sum.Aux[A, B, _]`.

> Wouldn't it be "obvious" that the return type of `apply` would have a
>   Sum#Out type equal to sum.Out?

No,

```
def apply[A <: Nat, B <: Nat](implicit sum: Sum[A, B]) = sum
```

is the same as

```
def apply[A <: Nat, B <: Nat](implicit sum: Sum[A, B]): Sum[A, B] = sum
```

The thing is that firstly you define implicits: either inductively with `sum1`, `sum2` or simply

```
implicit val sum00: Aux[_0, _0, _0] = new Sum[_0, _0] { type Out = _0 }
implicit val sum01: Aux[_0, _1, _1] = new Sum[_0, _1] { type Out = _1 }
implicit val sum10: Aux[_1, _0, _1] = new Sum[_1, _0] { type Out = _1 }
implicit val sum11: Aux[_1, _1, _2] = new Sum[_1, _1] { type Out = _2 }
...
```

Then when you write

```
def apply[A <: Nat, B <: Nat](implicit sum: Sum[A, B]): Aux[A, B, sum.Out] = sum
```

knowing just `A` and `B` is enough for resolving implicit. And every defined implicit "knows" its specific `C`. But if you return just `Sum[A, B]` this `C` will be forgotten.

You could define

```
def apply[A <: Nat, B <: Nat, C <: Nat](implicit sum: Aux[A, B, C]): Aux[A, B, C] = sum
```

but then you will have to call it specifying `C` manually: `Sum[_2, _3, _5]`.

> If we remove it and we just use `val x = Sum[_0, _1]`, it looks fine,
>   except adding `val y = Sum[x.Out, _1]` will not work, saying the
>   compiler couldn't find the implicit Sum.

Sure. `x.Out` is no longer `_1`, it's just some abstract `x.Out`, and implicit can't be resolved.