# Shapeless: holding Prepend and Split for delayed execution

Tags: scala, shapeless

My goal is to Wrap an HList and save enough information to perform prepend and split operations at a later time.

```
case class Wrap[L <: HList](wrapped: L)

val x = Wrap("x" :: "y" :: HNil)
val y = Wrap(1 :: 2 :: HNil)

case class Append[L1, L2](w1: Wrap[L1], w2: Wrap[L2], prepend: Prepend[L1, L2], length: Length[L1])

def append[L1, L2](w1: Wrap[L1], w2: Wrap[L2])(implicit prepend: Prepend[L1, L2], length: Length[L1]) = Append(w1, w2, prepend, length)

val xAppendY = append(x,y)

val merged = xAppendY.prepend(xAppendY.w1.wrapped, xAppendY.w2.wrapped)

val split = Split[xAppendY.prepend.Out, xAppendY.length.Out] // <-- error here

split.apply(merged)
```

This code fails with the implicit not found error:

`Implicit not found: shapeless.Ops.Split[xAppendY.prepend.Out, xAppendY.length.Out]. You requested to split at position xAppendY.length.Out, but the HList xAppendY.prepend.Out is too short.`

But it seems the the compiler should know that the types are `String :: String :: String :: String :: HNil` and `Nat._2`.  Is there something that I need to do to help the compiler out here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following version of code works:

```
  import shapeless.ops.hlist.{Length, Prepend, Split}
  import shapeless.{::, HList, HNil, Nat}

  case class Wrap[L <: HList](wrapped: L)

  val x = Wrap("x" :: "y" :: HNil)
  val y = Wrap(1 :: 2 :: HNil)

  case class Append[L1 <: HList, L2 <: HList, L3 <: HList, N <: Nat](w1: Wrap[L1], w2: Wrap[L2], prepend: Prepend.Aux[L1, L2, L3], length: Length.Aux[L1, N])

  def append[L1 <: HList, L2 <: HList, L3 <: HList, N <: Nat](w1: Wrap[L1], w2: Wrap[L2])(implicit prepend: Prepend.Aux[L1, L2, L3], length: Length.Aux[L1, N]) = Append(w1, w2, prepend, length)

  val xAppendY = append(x,y)

  val merged = xAppendY.prepend(xAppendY.w1.wrapped, xAppendY.w2.wrapped)

  val split = Split[xAppendY.prepend.Out, xAppendY.length.Out]

  split.apply(merged)
```

In your version of code `xAppendY.prepend` was of type `Prepend[L1, L2] = Prepend[L1, L2] { type Out }` rather than `Prepend.Aux[L1, L2, L3] = Prepend[L1, L2] { type Out = L3 }` for proper `L3` and `xAppendY.length` was of type `Length[L1] = Length[L1] { type Out }` rather than `Length.Aux[L1, N] = Length[L1] { type Out = N }` for proper `N`.

[Why do we need to specify a refined type (or its equivalent Aux) for the output of certain type computations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48627883/why-do-we-need-to-specify-a-refined-type-or-its-equivalent-aux-for-the-output/48673036#48673036)