# When are dependent types needed in Shapeless?

Tags: scala, shapeless, dependent-type

As I understand dependent types allow you to leave output types unspecified:

E.g., if you have a type class:

```
trait Last[In] {
  type Out
}
```

then you could summon an instance while leaving the output type unspecified:

```
implicitly(Last[String :: Int :: HNil]) // output type calculated as Int
```

And the Aux pattern allows you to specify the output type again:

```
implicitly(Last.Aux[String :: Int :: HNil, Int])
```

which you need in an implicit parameter list in order to do something useful with the output type ([to work around a Scala limitation on dependent types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43900674/understanding-the-aux-pattern-in-scala-type-system)).

But if you always need to specify (or assign a type param to) the output type, why bother using dependent types (and then Aux) in the first place?

I tried copying the `Last` type class from Shapeless' src, replacing `type Out` by an additional type param in the trait and removing Aux. It still works.

What is the situation when I actually need them?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48627883/why-do-we-need-to-specify-a-refined-type-or-its-equivalent-aux-for-the-output/48673036#48673036

Comment: @DmytroMitin I get that `Sum[A, B]` is not the same as `Sum[A, B] { type Out = C }` or `Sum.Aux[A, B, C]`. I'm asking why do I need `type Out` at all rather than just `Sum[A, B, C]`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34544660/why-is-the-aux-technique-required-for-type-level-computations

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I get that `Sum[A, B]` is not the same as `Sum[A, B] { type Out = C }` or
>   `Sum.Aux[A, B, C]`. I'm asking why do I need type `Out` at all rather than
>   just `Sum[A, B, C]`.

The difference is in partial application. For `trait MyTrait { type A; type B; type C }` you can specify some of types and not specify others (expecting that compiler infers them). But for `trait MyTrait[A, B, C]` you can only either specify all of them or not specify any of them.
For `Sum[A, B] { type Out }` you would prefer to specify `A`, `B` and not specify `Out` (expecting that compiler infers its value based on implicits existing in scope). Similarly for `trait Last[In] { type Out }` you would prefer to specify `In` and not specify `Out` (expecting that compiler infers its value).
So type parameters are more like inputs and type members are more like outputs.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R8GksuRw3VI

[Abstract types versus type parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3170821/abstract-types-versus-type-parameters) and linked questions

---

> But when exactly, would I prefer to specify `In` and not specify `Out`?

Let's consider the following example. It's a type class for addition of natural numbers:

```
sealed trait Nat
case object Zero extends Nat
type Zero = Zero.type
case class Succ[N <: Nat](n: N) extends Nat

type One = Succ[Zero]
type Two = Succ[One]
type Three = Succ[Two]
type Four = Succ[Three]
type Five = Succ[Four]

val one: One = Succ(Zero)
val two: Two = Succ(one)
val three: Three = Succ(two)
val four: Four = Succ(three)
val five: Five = Succ(four)

trait Add[N <: Nat, M <: Nat] {
  type Out <: Nat
  def apply(n: N, m: M): Out
}

object Add {
  type Aux[N <: Nat, M <: Nat, Out0 <: Nat] = Add[N, M] { type Out = Out0 }
  def instance[N <: Nat, M <: Nat, Out0 <: Nat](f: (N, M) => Out0): Aux[N, M, Out0] = new Add[N, M] {
    override type Out = Out0
    override def apply(n: N, m: M): Out = f(n, m)
  }

  implicit def zeroAdd[M <: Nat]: Aux[Zero, M, M] = instance((_, m) => m)
  implicit def succAdd[N <: Nat, M <: Nat, N_addM <: Nat](implicit add: Aux[N, M, N_addM]): Aux[Succ[N], M, Succ[N_addM]] =
    instance((succN, m) => Succ(add(succN.n, m)))
}
```

This type class works both on type level

```
implicitly[Add.Aux[Two, Three, Five]]
```

and value level

```
println(implicitly[Add[Two, Three]].apply(two, three))//Succ(Succ(Succ(Succ(Succ(Zero)))))
assert(implicitly[Add[Two, Three]].apply(two, three) == five)//ok
```

Now let's rewrite it with type parameter instead of type member:

```
trait Add[N <: Nat, M <: Nat, Out <: Nat] {
  def apply(n: N, m: M): Out
}

object Add {
  implicit def zeroAdd[M <: Nat]: Add[Zero, M, M] = (_, m) => m
  implicit def succAdd[N <: Nat, M <: Nat, N_addM <: Nat](implicit add: Add[N, M, N_addM]): Add[Succ[N], M, Succ[N_addM]] =
    (succN, m) => Succ(add(succN.n, m))
}
```

On type level it works similarly

```
implicitly[Add[Two, Three, Five]]
```

But on value level now you have to specify type `Five` while in the former case it was inferred by compiler.

```
println(implicitly[Add[Two, Three, Five]].apply(two, three))//Succ(Succ(Succ(Succ(Succ(Zero)))))
assert(implicitly[Add[Two, Three, Five]].apply(two, three) == five)//ok
```

So the difference is in partial application.

---

> But if you add a `+` syntax sugar as you normally would to make it
>   practical (shapeless also does it for everything), the dependent type
>   doesn't seem to matter

Syntax helps not always. For example let's consider a type class that accepts a type (but not value of this type) and produces a type and value of this type:

```
trait MyTrait {
  type T
}

object Object1 extends MyTrait
object Object2 extends MyTrait

trait TypeClass[In] {
  type Out
  def apply(): Out
}

object TypeClass {
  type Aux[In, Out0] = TypeClass[In] { type Out = Out0 }
  def instance[In, Out0](x: Out0): Aux[In, Out0] = new TypeClass[In] {
    override type Out = Out0
    override def apply(): Out = x
  }

  def apply[In](implicit tc: TypeClass[In]): Aux[In, tc.Out] = tc

  implicit val makeInstance1: Aux[Object1.T, Int] = instance(1)
  implicit val makeInstance2: Aux[Object2.T, String] = instance("a")
}

println(TypeClass[Object1.T].apply())//1
println(TypeClass[Object2.T].apply())//a
```

but if we make `Out` a type parameter then upon call we'll have to specify `Out` and there's no way to define extension method and infer type parameter `In` from element type since there are no elements of the types `Object1.T`, `Object2.T`.

Comment: But when exactly, would I prefer to specify `In` and not specify `Out`?
If you check the beginning of my question, I get what you're saying here.
What bothers me is that every time I want to do something useful with `Out` I get a reference to it via `Aux`, then I *didn't* prefer to "not specify it". E.g.: `def doSomething[A,B, Result](implicit sum: Sum.Aux[A,B,Result], somethingDone: MakeUseOfIt[Result]) = ???`

Comment: Fair point, I was happy for a minute. But if you add a `+` syntax sugar as you normally would to make it practical (shapeless also does it for everything), the dependent type doesn't seem to matter:

```
implicit class AddOps[A <: Nat](nat: A) {
  def +[B <: Nat, C <: Nat](other: B)(implicit add: Add[A, B, C]): C = add(nat, other)
}
```   

Then `one + two` still works on the value level and I don't need to know `C`, the compiler finds it for me.

Comment: Yes, I can't break your last example. And video you linked also helps: "type params vs. members are alternative ways to do the same and some things will be more easily done with one or another". Thanks Dmytro.