# How to convert an Int into Ordered (Scala)

Tags: scala, generics, types, type-bounds, f-bounded-polymorphism

I have declared a Value class in Scala as:

```scala
sealed abstract class Value extends Expression with Ordered[Value] {
  type T <: Ordered[T]
  def value: T

  override def compare(that: Value): Int = { ... } 
}
```

The reason for the type constraint T <: Ordered[T] is that I want to delegate the `compare` method in Value to `value: T`.

And then a concrete IntValue as:

```scala
case class IntValue(value: Int) extends Value {
  type T = Int
  // ... 
}
```

However, when I try to compile this code I get the following: ''

```
... incompatible type in overriding
[error] type T <: Ordered[IntValue.this.T] (defined in class Value);
[error]  found   : Int
[error]  required:  <: Ordered[IntValue.this.T]
[error]     (which expands to)   <: Ordered[Int]
[error]   type T = Int
```

I think that I should use some implicit conversion here, but it is not clear to me how to proceed.

Comment: Are you sure your error relates to the current version of your code? In the code you have `Ordered`. In the error you have `Ordering`.

Comment: thanks, @DmytroMitin, you are right. I fixed the error message.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez It turned out the meta-problem was delegating `compare` from `T` to `Value` :)

Answer (score 3):

The error is about incompatible type in overriding, not about implicits.

You should remove upper bound `type T <: Ordered[T]`.

`Int` doesn't extend `Ordered`.

Try type parameter rather than type member

```
sealed abstract class Value[T] extends /*Expression with*/ Ordered[Value[T]] {
  def value: T
  override def compare(that: Value[T]): Int
}

case class IntValue(value: Int) extends Value[Int] {
  override def compare(that: Value[Int]): Int = value.compare(that.value)
}
```

Similar code with type member

```
sealed abstract class Value extends /*Expression with*/ Ordered[Value {type T = self.T}] { self =>
  type T
  def value: T   
  override def compare(that: Value {type T = self.T}): Int
}

case class IntValue(value: Int) extends Value {
  type T = Int  
  override def compare(that: Value {type T = Int}): Int = value.compare(that.value)
}
```

is not possible because of `Error: illegal cyclic reference`.

[Scala: Abstract types vs generics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1154571/scala-abstract-types-vs-generics)

https://typelevel.org/blog/2015/07/13/type-members-parameters.html

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R8GksuRw3VI

https://tpolecat.github.io/2015/04/29/f-bounds.html

---

If you want to delegate then you should use [type class](https://kubuszok.com/2018/implicits-type-classes-and-extension-methods-part-1/#type-classes-in-scala) `Ordering` rather than OOP trait `Ordered`. `Int` doesn't extend `Ordered` but there is an instance of `Ordering` for `Int`

```
sealed abstract class Value[T] {
  def value: T
}

case class IntValue(value: Int) extends Value[Int]

implicit def valueOrdering[T, A](implicit 
  ev: A <:< Value[T], 
  ordering: Ordering[T]
): Ordering[A] = ordering.on(_.value)

import Ordering.Implicits._
IntValue(1) < IntValue(2) // -1
```

or

```
import Ordered._
IntValue(1) < IntValue(2) // true
IntValue(1).compare(IntValue(2)) // -1
```

---

Approach with type class can be used for type member

```
sealed abstract class Value {
  type T
  def value: T
}

case class IntValue(value: Int) extends Value {
  override type T = Int
}

implicit def valueOrdering[A <: Value](implicit 
  ordering: Ordering[A#T]
): Ordering[A] = ordering.on(_.value)

// implicit def valueOrdering[_T, A](implicit 
//   ev: A <:< Value { type T = _T }, 
//   ordering: Ordering[_T]
// ): Ordering[A] = ordering.on(_.value)
```

Comment: Thanks for your clarifications @DmytroMitin. The reason for the type constraint T <: Ordered[T] is that I want to delegate the `compare` method in Value to the "field" `value: T`.

Comment: @RodrigoBonifacio Well, `Int` doesn't extend `Ordered`. If you want to delegate then you should use type class `Ordering` rather than OOP trait `Ordered`. `Int` doesn't extend `Ordered` but there is an instance of `Ordering` for `Int`.

Comment: @RodrigoBonifacio By the way, approach with type class can be used for type member. See one more update.